# Click on Imageview inside of TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

here my code

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("saved", 
            new Intent(v.getContext(),Saved_jobs.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

    replaceView(view);
```

I am using this code to open new activity inside of tabHost and open activity perfectly and all control click event working fine

But when i click on imageview then application crashing

Imageview click event code

```
  imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starapplied);
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecentlyViewd.this);
                builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete this job?");
               // builder.setMessage("whould You like to save job");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      db.DeleteLocation(v.getTag().toString());
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Deleted !",10).show();
                     startActivity(new Intent(RecentlyViewd.this,RecentlyViewd.class));
                     finish();
                }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                          dialog.cancel();
                      }
                    });
                builder.show();
            }
         });
```

LogCat:

```
01-03 15:54:11.205: E/ActivityThread(1092): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
01-03 15:54:11.205: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(1092): Could not find a dictionary pack
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@b67b6b98 is not valid; is your activity running?
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at com.jobDiagnosis.RecentlyViewd$SavedAdapter$1.onClick(RecentlyViewd.java:196)
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-03 15:54:17.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2771):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  01-03 15:54:19.475: E/Trace(2806): error opening trace file: No such file or directory  (2)
01-03 15:54:19.815: E/ActivityThread(1092): Failed to find provider info for  com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
01-03 15:54:19.815: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(1092): Could not find a dictionary pack
01-03 15:54:19.925: E/ActivityThread(1092): Failed to find provider info for  com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
 01-03 15:54:19.925: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(1092): Could not find a dictionary pack
 01-03 15:54:20.265: E/BufferQueue(786): [] drainQueueLocked: BufferQueue has been  abandoned!
```

Please Help Me

**It's very important task for me**

Thanks in Adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ***TabGroupActivity*** then change to this one:

from

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecentlyViewd.this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
```

Comment: another issue is when i am open new activity using 'View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("saved", 
            new Intent(v.getContext(),Saved_jobs.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

    replaceView(view);' outside of Tabhost then tabhost not apperar

Comment: for that you have to call childActivity from parent Activity

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecentlyViewd.this);
```

use this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```